# Passing Nested Keys to Custom Array Lookup Function, PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a custom array lookup function which I pass both **array and key** to and it returns the value if it finds it or an empty string. It has been working well as intended only to realize that I cannot pass a nested key to it. By nesting I mean key like ***[outer-key][inner-key]***. The function (in a class) is:

```
public function getArrayValueSafely($dataArray, $dKey){
    if(!is_array($dataArray) || count($dataArray) < 1){
        return false;
    }
    if(strlen($dKey) < 1){
        return false;
    }
    $retVal = '';
    try {
        $retVal = $dataArray[$dKey];
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }           
    return $retVal;
}
```

The warning is always:

> Warning: Undefined array key "['SUBJECT_STRANDS']['RELIGION']"

Whether the keys is given as: `['SUBJECT_STRANDS']['RELIGION']` or `[SUBJECT_STRANDS][RELIGION]`; the keys are definitely existing.
Any pointers to solve this will be highly appreciated as I am currently forced to pull the data using **outer-key**, then do a second lookup using **inner-key**.

Sample call as requested by @chris-haas:

```
$currentKey = "['SUBJECT_STRANDS']['RELIGION']";    
//$currentKey = "[SUBJECT_STRANDS][RELIGION]"; //tried this also
$currentStrands = $this->getArrayValueSafely($lastExamData, $currentKey);
```

Comment: Please post a sample of code that is calling this. I’m curious what a “nested” key looks like in `$dKey` specifically.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, posted.

Comment: You appear to be using strings that look like PHP array keys, but aren’t. Although not invalid, it is strange to see square brackets in the key.

Answer (score 1):

You could maintain a reference of the current array, while iterating over the keys you want to traverse.

```php
function getArrayValueSafely($dataArray, $keys)
{
    $ref = &$dataArray; // Start with the given array
    foreach ($keys as $key) { // loop over the keys
        if (! isset($ref[$key])) { // key not found, return.
            return false;
        }
        $ref = $ref[$key]; // move the pointer on sub array.
    }
    return $ref; // return reference value.
}


// Sample Data :
$lastExamData   = ['SUBJECT_STRANDS' => ['RELIGION' => 'data']];

// Keys to traverse :
$currentKey     = ['SUBJECT_STRANDS', 'RELIGION'];

// Get the value
$currentStrands = getArrayValueSafely($lastExamData, $currentKey);
var_dump($currentStrands); // string(4) "data"
```

[live demo](https://3v4l.org/uVosK)

Comment: I have just tested this and it works; thanks @Syscall